# UICollectionView Touch cancellation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view with a tap gesture recognizer, behind a UICollectionView. I need to cancel the propagation of the touch after the didSelectItemAt method from the collection view is invoked.

However, the only property in UICollectionView related to touches that I see is canCancelContentTouches and it does not seem to be working the way I intend it to.

I can think of having a flag and then checking if the flag has changed in the gesture action but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Heyy, any luck with the solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult without any code to reference.

However, if you declare the tap recognizer as an instance variable, you can then remove it from the view in your didSelect call.